# Dynamically setting a range for MAX() or MIN() functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a gantt chart spreadsheet and trying to make the impossible work (it seems so)

[image]

Basically I'm trying to achieve is that dates in U and W columns would have a dynamically set range for min or max functions based on G column value (type of row) so everything that is between two PS (Primary section) and between two S (sections) would be defined as a range.

The catch is that row type is set by user, and the number of rows can be from 1 to N-th, so the fixed MIN or MAX formula is not really an option

Getting the start of the range is easy - basic `IF(G13="PS",...,...)`

The difficult part, where I need help, is getting the last range row that is just before the next S or PS type.

See example ranges below.

[image]

Current achieved result: `=MAX(IF(tipas="PS",INDIRECT("U" & ROW(id)),IF(tipas="S",INDIRECT("U" & ROW(id)),"")):U17)`

Full cell formula:

```
    =IFERROR(IF(AND(tipas<>"",tipas="PS"),MAX(INDIRECT("U" & ROW(id):U17),
IF(AND(tipas<>"",tipas="S"),MAX(INDIRECT("U" & ROW(id):U17),
    
    'formulas to get the date for other types'
    
    IF(plan.pradzia<>"",plano.pabaigos.skaic,IF(plan.pabaiga<>"",plan.pabaiga,IF(eilNr<>"",
    IF(darbo.priklausomumas="PrPb",prpb.skaic,IF(darbo.priklausomumas="PbPb",pbpb.skaic,plano.pabaigos.skaic)),""))))),"")
```

> **tipas** is a nemed range for G column

How could I get the U17 value dynamically based on column G value?

Comment: It smells like the same problem you had asked about previously. It's not like it's the same question, just the solution might be similar. An AGGREGATE function will most likely do the trick. I'll give it a shot tomorrow if none else will have already solved. Have a look to the previous solution while you're waiting (especially the aggregate part).

Comment: Much appreciated. And yeah I figured that was kinda same problem when I posted. I am trying few formulas in the dummy colums and just trying to figure out the AGGREGATE (that one is new to Me )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i don't know what cells are avaiable, let's assume that the range HA:HF is avaiable. Place these formulas accordingly:

| ADDRESS | OUTCOME DESCRIPTION | FORMULA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HA13 | Row of any PS cell. | =IF($G13="PS",ROW($G13),"") |
| HB13 | Row of any PS or S cell. | =IF(OR($G13="PS",$G13="S"),ROW($G13),"") |
| HC13 | Address of the range for the PS section in the U column (reported on the proper PS row). | =IF($G13="PS",IF(OR(OFFSET($G13,1,0)="PS",OFFSET($G13,1,0)=""),"","U"&MAX(HA$13:HA13)+1&":U"&IF(MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1=0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($G13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($G:$G),CELL("col",$G:$G),1,1))="",0),FALSE)+ROW($G13),MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1)),"") |
| HD13 | Address of the range for the S section in the U column (reported on the proper S row). | =IF($G13="S",IF(OR(OFFSET($G13,1,0)="PS",OFFSET($G13,1,0)="S",OFFSET($G13,1,0)=""),"","U"&MAX(HB$13:HB13)+1&":U"&IF(MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HB13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HB:HB),CELL("col",HB:HB),1,1)))-1=0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($G13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($G:$G),CELL("col",$G:$G),1,1))="",0),FALSE)+ROW($G13),MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HB13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HB:HB),CELL("col",HB:HB),1,1)))-1)),"") |
| HE13 | Address of the range for the PS section in the W column (reported on the proper PS row). | =IF($G13="PS",IF(OR(OFFSET($G13,1,0)="PS",OFFSET($G13,1,0)=""),"","W"&MAX(HA$13:HA13)+1&":W"&IF(MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1=0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($G13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($G:$G),CELL("col",$G:$G),1,1))="",0),FALSE)+ROW($G13),MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1)),"") |
| HF13 | Address of the range for the S section in the W column (reported on the proper S row). | =IF($G13="S",IF(OR(OFFSET($G13,1,0)="PS",OFFSET($G13,1,0)="S",OFFSET($G13,1,0)=""),"","W"&MAX(HB$13:HB13)+1&":W"&IF(MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HB13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HB:HB),CELL("col",HB:HB),1,1)))-1=0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($G13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($G:$G),CELL("col",$G:$G),1,1))="",0),FALSE)+ROW($G13),MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HB13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HB:HB),CELL("col",HB:HB),1,1)))-1)),"") |

Then drag the cells to cover the whole list. You can use an INDIRECT function to integrate the addresses in your formulas. For example:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(HC13))
```

or

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(IF($G13="PS",IF(OR(OFFSET($G13,1,0)="PS",OFFSET($G13,1,0)=""),"","U"&MAX(HA$13:HA13)+1&":U"&IF(MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1=0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($G13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($G:$G),CELL("col",$G:$G),1,1))="",0),FALSE)+ROW($G13),MIN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(HA13,1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(HA:HA),CELL("col",HA:HA),1,1)))-1)),"")))
```

I've tried a AGGREGATE based solution, but it appeared to be slower and possibly needed more columns. This solution should be lighter, but in case of a long list it might still be too slow. In such case, a VBA solution might be better with a user defined function. Then again, the questions' tag were `excel` and `excel-formula`. I might try a user defined function if needed.